# Randomly grab string from array, use as placeholder text, and equate to answer string in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, random, uitextfield

I have two UITextFields that get the placeHolder.text randomly from an array. The part I am stuck on, is having an element in an array of answers, correspond to the placeHolder text.

Meaning: placeHolder.text is a question, user text input is the answer, and we check that the user answer is the same as the hard coded value.

sample code:

```
   let questionArray = ["name of your cat?", "name of your other cat?"]
   let questionArray2 = { more stupid questions ]
 
    let answerArray = ["cat damen", "diabetes"]
    let answerArray2 = [ more stupid answers ]

    var answerContainer: String()
    var answerContainer2: String()

    uitextField1.placeHolder = questionArray.randomElement()
    uitextField2.placeHolder = questionArray2.randomElement()
    
    Heres where I get stupid :
    
    func answerGenerator {
       if UItextField1.placeHolder == questionArray[0] {
          answerContainer = answerArray[0]
      }
    }

func submit(_ sender: UIButton) {
       if uitextField.text == answerContainer && uitextField2.text == answerContainer2 { 
   do good stuff 
    }
  }
```

I tried using a dictionary, but got stuck. I also thought about an Enum / Switch Case, but also got stuck as I have two textFields that need the placeHolder generated randomly.

so what happens is the actual answer that's supposed to be allocated to its question, maybe it happens, but I'm not grabbing it correctly to compare what the user will type in the textfield.

Its so easy, but I'm overthinking this.

Comment: Don't use `randomElement()`, get a random index and use it on both question and answer array. `let index = Int.random(in:0..< questionArray.count)`

Comment: Ahh, so grab the index randomly, assign the value of said index to placeHolder. Use the same method to equate the answer index to question index and compare the answer index to the user inputs text ?

Comment: Yes, you only need to keep track of the current index and then use it when getting first the question and then the answer to compare it with the user input

Comment: Question: do I use random on answer array as well or just get question array and then do  if index == 2 { get matching index of answer array }